# shieldui grid scrolling enabled using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, scroll, grid, shieldui

I am using the Shield UI grid and wanted to use the 'Scrolling Enabled="true"' option.  I have it set-up like on their demo page (**https://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/grid-general/scrolling**) and I get the same results as their demo.  For the ASP.Net tab the grid expands beyond the boundary of the upper area used by the other 3 tabs.

Has anyone run into this and have a fix for it?

[Image of Shield UI Demo Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVLsd.png)

Answer (score 1):

I received an e-mail from Shield UI support with a fix.  This can also be seen on their demo page now.

Using a css class you can use the overflow option:

```
.gridCSS {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be the problem with the rendering. After reporting the issue to Shield UI, they have [fixed the problem](http://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/grid-general/scrolling).